# Is there anything similar to JetBrains IDEs Navigation bar in Microsoft IDEs especially in Visual Studio and SSMS

Tags: visual-studio, ide, ssms, jetbrains-ide

The navigator bar feature of JetBrains IDEs is very helpful to keep track of the location of file and to see if you are in the correct directory.
I will like this feature especially in SSMS where you cannot have any way to know what is the location of the script you have opened. I have saved some queries which I need to run on different servers with small changes.

So is there a way I can see what is the file location of the scripts I have opened so that I may not make any unwanted changes in those files?
Does Visual Studio and SSMS has something similar to Navigation bar in JetBrains IDEs?

**P.S.** Please keep in mind the fact that I loved using it in CLion IDE and not having something similar in VS or SSMS is kind of disappointing. And I tend to make such mistakes quite often and keeping copies is necessary for me.

Comment: Can you show a picture of what you exactly mean by "Navigation bar"? In Visual Studio, you can always hover over the file name at the top of the edit window to see the full path.

Comment: Do you mean the solution explorer?

Comment: @PMF It's basically breadcrumbs with the file path relative to the project root (or full path if it's outside of the project). Have a look at #1 here (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/guided-tour-around-the-user-interface.html) or here (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/new-ui.html#navigation_bar -- it's at the bottom now by default, but can be put back at the top)

Answer (score 0):

In VS, you'll normally not need that (at least I never missed something like that). You have the solution explorer on the left side, showing the project-relative paths. You can hover over the tab of an open file to show the full path if you need to.

Since one works with projects and solutions in VS, it's very rare that a file outside of the project is open in the IDE. You shouldn't mix files from different solutions, or different working copies or from server and local in the same instance of VS. For editing standalone script files, VS is probably the wrong tool, use a text editor or VS code for that.

Comment: I know this is not a usual behavior to open single file and not the project in VS. I just want know if there is a way to improve my IDE for my ease. and the more critical one I need this for is SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

[Editor Bar](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jiripolasek.EditorBar) extension prominently displays both file path and project name in the editor bar.

Comment: yes, thanks and is there anything similar for SQL SERVER Management Studio?

Comment: @mgh I'm not aware of something similar for SSMS.